# cutorch takes a long time to import

Tags: torch

Importing cutorch takes something like 45 seconds, which seems like an extremely long time, since I don't see any heavy initialization under the hood that it should be doing.  Is this a lot longer than expected?  What could be causing this problem?

I am running Arch-Linux on i7 6700k, 1080 gtx.